# Android: Cant log in using PHP MySQL upload @ http://ramses.freewha.com/

Tags: php, android, mysql

Ok so I accidentally replace my log in file with a new php file. I have no backup because I edit it online. The problem is, same code on my java file, and different code in my php file uploaded online, everytime I logged in the toast appear says "`</script>`". Here's my code:

Java file:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String USER_NAME = "Username";
    public static final String password = "password";

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://stiswms.ueuo.com/login.php";

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    private Button buttonLogin;
    private Button btAbout;
    private Button btDev;
    private Button btContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUserLogin);
        btAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btDev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDev);
        btContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);

        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
        btDev.setOnClickListener(this);
        btContact.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void login(){
        String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        userLogin(username,password);
    }

    private void userLogin(final String username, final String password){
        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this,"Please Wait",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(USER_NAME,username);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("username",params[0]);
                data.put("password",params[1]);

                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }

        UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
        ulc.execute(username,password);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonLogin){
            login();
        }
        else if(v== btAbout){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(v== btContact){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Contact.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(v== btDev){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Dev.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

PHP file: login.php

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';

connect();
$username=$_POST['loginUsername'];
$password=$_POST['loginPassword'];
$login = querydb("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password' limit 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($login) > 0 ){   

        $getrow = mysqli_fetch_object($login);
        $accid=$getrow->Account_ID;
        $acctype=$getrow->Account_Type;
        $_SESSION['acctype']=$acctype;
        $_SESSION['accid']=$accid;
        header("location:mainhome.php");
    }else{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
        window.location="index.php";
    </script>
    <?php
    }   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change these lines:

```
data.put("username",params[0]);
data.put("password",params[1]);
```

to :

```
data.put("loginUsername",params[0]);
data.put("loginPassword",params[1]);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to change you php file then use this:

```
<?php
require 'functions.php';

connect();
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$login = querydb("SELECT * FROM tbl_accounts WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password' limit 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($login) > 0 ){   

        $getrow = mysqli_fetch_object($login);
        $accid=$getrow->Account_ID;
        $acctype=$getrow->Account_Type;
        echo 'success';
        $_SESSION['acctype']=$acctype;
        $_SESSION['accid']=$accid;
        header("location:mainhome.php");
    }else{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
        window.location="index.php";
    </script>
    <?php
    }


?>
```

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE html>" in toast. Help me sir

Comment: My problem now is everytime I logged in toast says "<!DOCTYPE html>" and didn't go on the next page though my username and pass is correct.